# How to create A record having multiple IP in route53 using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to create a A type of record having multiple IPs in aws route53 using aws cli. I didn't find exact command . Can somebody help me.

example.
demoHC.hc.xyz.com should have 2-3 IP

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: /usr/local/bin/aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id xxxxxxxxE1P --change-batch '{"Changes":[{"Action":"CREATE","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"anujhc.hc.xyz.com","Type":"A","TTL":300,"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"1.2.3.4"}]}}]}'. added another Value for second IP. but not working.

Comment: Edit your question with your example. Did you add the second IP to the ResourceRecords array at the same time you executed the command? Please be specific on "but did not work ....".

Comment: It is resolved now. 2 changes. action: should be UPSERT and add second record like this. "ResourceRecords":[‌​{"Value":"1.2.3.4"},{"Value":"5.6.7.8"}]. Thanks guys for looking into this.

Comment: I do not know why some people do not like this question. The documentation by AWS is poor for this specific purpose. After reading a few pages still cannot find a clear text saying this cannot be done in aws Console.

Answer (score 2):

You must create multiple `Value` records:

```
{
   "Changes":[
      {
         "Action":"CREATE",
         "ResourceRecordSet":{
            "Name":‌​"anujhc.hc.xyz.com",
            ‌​"Type":"A",
            "TTL":300,
            "ResourceRecords":[
               ‌​{
                  "Value":"1.2.3.4"
               },
               ​{
                  "Value":"8.8.8.8"
               },
               ​{
                  "Value":"123.123.123.123"
               }
            ]            ‌​
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is create-traffic-policy (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/create-traffic-policy.html)

Part of the traffic policy includes how you want to distribute traffic (you have a few options including weighted or via geolocation) the simplest way is a round robin approach, where you have equally weighted endpoints.

Here's some code, taken from (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/api-policies-traffic-policy-document-format.html#traffic-policy-document-format-examples)

```
{
  "AWSPolicyFormatVersion":"2015-10-01",
  "RecordType":"A",
  "StartRule":"round_robin",
  "Endpoints":{
    "srv1":{
      "Type":"value",
      "Value":"192.0.2.1"
    },
    "srv2":{
      "Type":"value",
      "Value":"192.0.2.2"
    },
    "srv3":{
      "Type":"value",
      "Value":"192.0.2.3"
    }
  },
  "Rules":{
    "round_robin":{
      "RuleType":"weighted",
      "Items":[
        {
          "EndpointReference":"srv1",
          "Weight":"3",
          "HealthCheck":"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
        },
        {
          "EndpointReference":"srv2",
          "Weight":"1",
          "HealthCheck":"22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
        },
        {
          "EndpointReference":"srv3",
          "Weight":"1",
          "HealthCheck":"33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

since you're going to need to pass in json you might benefit from this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/generate-cli-skeleton.html